foreach duplica los elementos <li> de una lista
Estoy teniendo un poco de problemas con un código en php. He creado un array multidimensional para que me cree código html, en concreto me tiene que crear objetos li. El problema radica a la hora de rellenar datos en los campos id de cada li y otros campos en esa linea, me crea los 5 li que me debe de crear, pero duplicados y partidos o sea unos datos en un li y el resto en otro li, como pueden ver en este fragmento de código html:


<!-- ELEMENTOS DUPLICADOS -->
<a id="LATEST" data-track-category="MENU" data-track-action="VIDEOS" data-track="LATEST" href="#" latest="">LATEST</a>
<!-- Los dos primeros LATEST estan bien , el tercero deberia de ser scenes/ y el nombre beberia de ser mas recientes... -->
<a id="LATEST" data-track-category="MENU" data-track-action="VIDEOS" data-track="LATEST" href="#" latest="">LATEST</a>
<!-- Este sobra -->
<!-- ELEMENTOS EN OTRO li -->
<a id="scenes/" data-track-category="MENU" data-track-action="VIDEOS" data-track="scenes/" href="#" scenes="">scenes/</a>
<!-- Este tiene scenes/ que deberia de ir en el campo href de la linea 1 -->
<a id="más" recientes="" data-track-category="MENU" data-track-action="VIDEOS" data-track="más" href="#" más="">más recientes</a>
<!-- Este tiene nombre que deberia de ir en el campo href de la linea 1 -->



Y así consecutivamente con los 5 li que debe crear, como pueden ver en la imagen que subo...
Imagen del Resultado
Aquí el código php que he creado:
$Cards = array(
    0 => array("id" => "LATEST", "data-track" => "LATEST", "href" => "scenes/", "Name" => "más recientes"),
    1 => array("id" => "TOP", "data-track" => "TOP",  "href" => "scenes/popular/", "Name" => "Top"),
    2 => array("id" => "MOVIES", "data-track" => "MOVIES", "href" => "movies/", "Name" => "Películas"),
    3 => array("id" => "EXTRAS", "data-track" => "MOVIES", "href" => "extras/", "Name" => "Extras"),
    4 => array("id" => "CATEGORIES", "data-track" => "CATEGORIES", "href4" => "categories", "Name" => "categorías")
); 
$li_item = "<li class='first-view'>";
foreach ($Cards as $Card) {
    foreach ($Card as $clave => $valor) {
        /*echo '$valor'. "\n";*/
        echo"<a id=".$valor." data-track-category='MENU' data-track-action='VIDEOS' data-track=".$valor." href='#'".$valor.">".$valor."</a>";
    }       
    $li_item .= "</li>";
echo $li_item;
echo "<br>";
}            
?>

Espero me puedan ayudar o darme alguna sugerencia sobre dónde esta el error.
Gracias y saludos

El problema está en que estás iterando innecesariamente dos veces sobre el mismo array.
Cambia el segundo foreach por la construcción correcta del HTML.
Te dejo el código como debe ser:
$Cards = array(
    array("id" => "LATEST", "data-track" => "LATEST", "href" => "scenes/", "Name" => "más recientes"),
    array("id" => "TOP", "data-track" => "TOP", "href" => "scenes/popular/", "Name" => "Top"),
    array("id" => "MOVIES", "data-track" => "MOVIES", "href" => "movies/", "Name" => "Películas"),
    array("id" => "EXTRAS", "data-track" => "MOVIES", "href" => "extras/", "Name" => "Extras"),
    array("id" => "CATEGORIES", "data-track" => "CATEGORIES", "href" => "categories", "Name" => "categorías")
); 

foreach ($Cards as $Card) {
    echo "<li class='first-view'><a id='{$Card['id']}' data-track-category='MENU' data-track-action='VIDEOS' data-track='{$Card['data-track']}' href='{$Card['href']}'>{$Card['Name']}</a></li>";
}
?>


Si esta respuesta te satisface no olvides marcarla como aceptada para evitar redundancias cuando alguien más pregunte lo mismo.

Gracias, no habia caido en eso , me ha funcionado a la primera.. mil gracias

Sí, la "respuesta aceptada" es la marca verde, cuando está marcada, indica a otros programadores que se ha encontrado una solución, de esa manera el sitio se mantiene ordenado y ayuda a enfocarse en preguntas urgentes que aún no tienen solución. Gracias!
